# How to bypass username validation in ebSecurity.GeneratePasswordResetToken

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to implement WebSecurity.GeneratePasswordResetToken in my MVC application.

Here is part of my method that should send a link to reset a users password link:

```
 [HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult SendPasswordLink(ForgotPassword email)
{
    var emailHelp = new Helper();

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var token =
        WebSecurity.GeneratePasswordResetToken(email.EmailAddress, 60);
```

At the line in the above code where I try to assign the token I keep getting this error:

```
No user found that has the name test@site.com
```

Before attempting to call the SendPasswordLink method I have already implemented my own validation for verifying if a user is valid.

How can I bypass/workaround the WebSecurity username validation:

All I need is to just generate a token to append to my password reset link

Comment: How do you expect [WebSecurity.ResetPassword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity.resetpassword(v=vs.111).aspx) to work if the generated token isn't tied to the user?  This doesn't sound like a code problem, but more likely a design problem.

Comment: Is there another way to add a token using websecurity that expires?

Comment: No there isn't. It sounds like you need to write your own provider.